# android button enlarging on click

Tags: java, android, xml, button, onclick

I have a program where I want to display 2 buttons that are arrows pointing left and right. Both are images and I am required to have them on my calculator type program. If I hit the right arrow, I want the field where there is a calculation involved to increase, and the button to get bigger. I have 6 images: a small arrow (left and right), a medium (left and right), and a large (left and right) set. how would I go about creating these buttons?

the link to the lab homework is here:

http://penguin.ewu.edu/cscd439/android/Summer_12/cscd439_l2.html

I just dont really understand how to create a button off of an image I download, and how to make the image change on click.

Comment: if you click on right arrow than only right arrow should get bigger?

Comment: yes. i believe so. it doesnt actually specify on the prompt

Comment: i might be missing something, but on the link you provided, nothing is said about the image growing in size, maybe they come in different sizes for different resolutions.

Comment: you know you might be right. this teacher is not very clear. but i was going to do it just incase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to increase the button image size and edit text field size on button click then simply replace the smaller images with the images of bigger size you want ,
like this

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                 button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonimg);

                    edittext1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edimg);
            }
        });
```

here

buttonimg and edimg are images in drawable folder

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your arrow button is an imageview with its drawable set to the small arrow button image (which is in your res/drawable folder) So, what you need to do is register an onClickListener to your imageView (the arrow button). Then, in the onClick function, do all your necessary stuff, such as setting the imageView's image to the new larger arrow and updating the text in the box. It should be pretty simple.

Here is an example. I just wrote this up off the top of my head, so don't expect it to work perfectly, but it should give you an idea of what to do.

```
ImageView rightArrow = findViewById(R.id.yourArrowImageViewID);
rightArrow.setOnClickListener( new View.onClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(view v){
        v.setImageResource(R.drawable.largerArrow);
        YourTextView.setText(<larger tip percent>);
    }//end onClick
  }//end new View.onClickListener
);//end setOnClickListener
```

Comment: so i put the pictures in that res drawable folder?

Comment: ... yes, that is where images go for Android.

Answer (score 0):

you can set a smallbutton as a image button in android xml file then after onclick you can replace smallbutton with largebutton by below code.

```
 button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.buttonsmall);

 bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.largebutton);

 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
           button.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    });
```